# child element innerText from parent with id

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change a specific child element's innerText of a parent who has a dynamic id (it's assigned the ID number from retrieved data). I thought the following would work:

```
var childElement = document.querySelectorAll('#' + serverResponse[0].id + ' .childElementClass');
childElement.innerText = "changed";
```

When I try this, it doesn't give me an error, it doesn't change anything and I think I may be misunderstand what .querySelectorAll does exactly. How should I be doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) actually returns a `NodeList`. If you know there is just going to be one element, use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns the first actual element matching the query.

```
var childElement = document.querySelector('#' + serverResponse[0].id + ' .childElementClass');
childElement.innerText = "changed";
```

Comment: So when I do that, I get "cannot set property innerText of null. The thing is I know it's there. I also tried 'p.childElementClass' and that gave me the same response. If i put some class name I know doesn't exist, it doesn't show an error, but it doesn't show anything at all

Comment: I made a quick jsbin and it seems to work. http://jsbin.com/kiqutiwuwu/edit?html,js,output Maybe edit it to match what you have and I can take a look.